# Dynamic Forms (Formsets) in Flask / WTForms?

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

In Django you have a multiple form feature called Formsets, which you can use to create multiple forms into the same template.  I am trying to achieve something similar in Flask / WTforms.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('request-accept') }}" method='post'>           
   <table>
        <tbody>
            {% for request in requests %}
                    <tr>                    
                        <td>                        
                           <div class="person-header">
                              <img src="{{request.profile_pic_url}}" class="img-circle profile-image"/>
                              <p class="person-header-text">{{request.fullname()}}</p>    
                           </div>
                       </td>                
                       <td>
                           <input type="checkbox" id="{{request.key.urlsafe()}}" name="checkbox{{loop.index}}">
                       </td>                    
                   </tr>
           {% endfor %}
    </tbody>            
  </table>

  <input class='submit btn btn-primary' type=submit value="Connect">            
</form>
```

The idea is having one form that wrapps all the checkboxes, which the user like to tick to become friends with.  As it currently stands I am not really generating any form class in Flask, since I don't know how to make a dynamic FormSet, hence I create the form dynamically inside the html.

The caveat is though, I don't know how to retrieve the selected `user id` via the checkbox. (I have stored it in the `id` because I didn't know better)

But I can't access the id in `request.values['checkbox1']`. I can only see if its `on` or `off`.

Any suggestions how to solve this please?

Answer (score 11):

### The problem

Your problem is that `id` is not sent back to the server - only `value` is ... and since your checkboxes don't *have* a `value` attribute the default value is used, which happens to be `on`.

Since you tagged this with [wtforms](/questions/tagged/wtforms), I'll give you an example of how you *could* be doing this.

### Never have this issue again

The WTForms' documentation has an [example class that will create a list of checkboxes for you](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/specific_problems.html#specialty-field-tricks):

```
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    """
    A multiple-select, except displays a list of checkboxes.

    Iterating the field will produce subfields, allowing custom rendering of
    the enclosed checkbox fields.
    """
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()
```

You would use this field in your custom form in this manner:

```
class FriendsForm(Form):
    potential_friends = MultiCheckboxField("Friends", coerce=int)

# ... later ...

@app.route("/add-friends", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_friends():
    form = FriendsForm(request.form)
    # lookup friends, for now we'll use a static list
    form.potential_friends.choices = [(1, "Sam"), (2, "Joe")]

    # We'll also need a mapping of IDs to Person instances
    # (Made up for this example - use your own ;-) )
    mapping = {
        1: Person("Sam", profile_pic="sam.jpg"),
        2: Person("Joe", profile_pic="joe.png")
    }

    if request.method == "POST":
        # Mark new friends

    return render_template("friends.html", form=form, persons=mapping)
```

Then, in `friends.html` you can iterate over the `form.potential_friends` field:

```
{% for person in form.potential_friends %}
    persons[person.data].profile_pic :: {{person.label}} :: {{person}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

You can customize your HTML inside the `for` loop. My particular example *should* render (with a few more attributes, like `for` and `name`):

```
sam.jpg :: <label>Sam</label> :: <input type="checkbox" value="1">
joe.png :: <label>Joe</label> :: <input type="checkbox" value="2">
```

Comment: choices need to go into the *MultiCheckboxField*: 
change ```form.choices = ...```  to ```form.potential_friends.choices = ...```

Comment: @stefanjunker - yes, that is indeed a typo - which is now fixed!  Thanks for helping make the question better!

Answer (score 0):

I personnally would add a `hidden` input field in your fieldset under each checkbox with a name such as "friend_nametag1" and a value corresponding to the friend's ID. With the 1 being incremented for every "friend". You can thus look it up in flask view using  something like

```
friend_list = []
list_of_checkboxes = ... (fetch from request.form... ?)
dict_of_friend_nametags = ... (build from request.form... ?)
if 'checkbox1' in list_of_checkboxes:
    friend_list.append(dict_of_friend_nametags.get('friend_nametag1')
```

Obviously you can use some sort of logic to have an incremental index (the "1" in "checkbox1" in this case).

I'm not too familiar with WTForms so there might be a better way to do this, but this solution is fairly straightforward to implement with your current code.

If you want a FieldSet or FormSet I would suggest you use the FormField in conjunction with the FieldList with the related docs here : http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/dev/fields.html#field-enclosures

p.s.: I would not recommend using `request` as a variable name in your template or your code as it may shadow the global `request` of flask ? XD